# MissingMethodException in new Grails project

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy

A previous employee at the company I work at made a fancy module in Grails 1.2, but noone knows how to set it up on a local machine.

I'm trying to set up a test project from scratch, just to get that to work, but it seems like IntelliJ is working against me. When I make a new project in IntelliJ,  it runs a CreateApp script, that fails like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java" -Dgrails.home=C:/tools/grails-1.2.5 "-Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:/tools/grails-1.2.5/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath C:\tools\grails-1.2.5\lib\groovy-all-1.6.8.jar;C:\tools\grails-1.2.5\dist\grails-bootstrap-1.2.5.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:/tools/grails-1.2.5/conf/groovy-starter.conf "create-app grailstest2 --inplace"
Welcome to Grails 1.2.5 - [url]http://grails.org/[/url]
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: C:/tools/grails-1.2.5

Base Directory: C:\grailstest2
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 972ms.
Running script C:\tools\grails-1.2.5\scripts\CreateApp_.groovy
Error executing script CreateApp: No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.toBoolean() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.toBoolean() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
at _GrailsSettings_groovy.run(_GrailsSettings_groovy:74)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsClasspath_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsClasspath_groovy.run(_GrailsClasspath_groovy:32)
at _GrailsClasspath_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsEvents_groovy.run(_GrailsEvents_groovy:30)
at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsClean_groovy.run(_GrailsClean_groovy:29)
at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsPlugins_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsPlugins_groovy.run(_GrailsPlugins_groovy:28)
at _GrailsPlugins_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsCreateProject_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsCreateProject_groovy.run(_GrailsCreateProject_groovy:28)
at _GrailsCreateProject_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at CreateApp_.run(CreateApp_:25)
at CreateApp_$run.call(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.processTargets(Gant.groovy:494)
at gant.Gant.processTargets(Gant.groovy:480)
Error executing script CreateApp: No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.toBoolean() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

This is the same error I get when I try to build the work module, so I figure I botched the SDK installation, but I don't remember doing any other than extracting the zip-file and setting path variables.

Where did I screw up?

Comment: you are using JDK8 with grails 1.2.5 version. Is it true? From the logs look like these are highly incompatible.

Comment: You should really upgrade to something newer than Grails 1.x. Grails 2.x is in maintenance mode, so Grails 3.x is where the new stuff happens.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati I set it to JDK5 and it worked. For my work project, I had to change my paths. Where do I force this in the project, so I can still use JDK8 in my other projects?

Comment: @sbglasius I agree with you, but our automated tests are pretty non-existant, so it'll take a good amount of time. My first step is getting it to work as it is, though :)

Comment: @Boz0r For that you could use idea to work with jdk5 for this project. But with this you have to deploy on local using idea itself.

Comment: If I set it to JDK5 in IntelliJ it fails again when starting grails, I guess since grails still uses JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 1):

> Where did I screw up?

Grails 1.2.5 will not support JDK 1.8.  The first version of Grails with real support for JDK 1.8 is Grails 2.5.